# Let $f$ be continuous on a compact set $D$. Show that the set $f(D)$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, proof-writing

**Problem.** Let $f$ be a function which is continuous on a compact set $D$. Show that $f(D)$ is bounded. Appeal only to the following definitions:

(i) A function $f$ on a domain $D$ is continuous at a point $c\in D$ *if and only if*, for all sequences $\langle a_n \rangle$ in $D$ convergent to $c$, the sequence $\langle f(a_n) \rangle$ is convergent to $f(c)$.

(ii) A set $S$ is compact *if and only if* every sequence of terms in $S$ has a subsequence convergent to a limit that is also in $S$.

---

**Attempt.** Given access to a couple of common theorems, this would be relatively straightforward. Instead, however, I'm asked to provide this *directly* and *only* from the given definitions. Here's what I have so far:

> Select an arbitrary sequence of terms in $\langle a_n \rangle$ in $D$.
> By compactness, this sequence has a subsequence $\langle {a_k}_n
>  \rangle$ convergent to a limit also in $D$.
>
> Since $f$ is continuous on $D$, and $\langle {a_k}_n\rangle$ is convergent to
> an element of $D$ (call it $c$), then $\langle f({a_k}_n)\rangle$ is
> convergent to $f(c)$. And since $\langle f({a_k}_n) \rangle$ is
> convergent, it is bounded.

It isn't clear to me how (or if) this extends to the entirety of $f(D)$ being bounded. How might I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

I suppose we're talking about real (scalar) functions $\;f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\;$ . Suppose $\;f(D)\;$ isn't bounded $\;\implies\;$ for any $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ there exists $\;x_n\in D\;$ s.t. $\;f(x_n)>N\;$ .

- What can you say about the sequence $\;\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;$ ?

** But $\;f\;$ is continuous, so if a sequence converges to a point $\;x_0\;$ in $\;D\;$ then the sequence of values of $\;f\;$ on that sequence converges to $\;f(x_0)\;$ , so...?

Comment: Thanks, I see. So, we can say that the sequence $\{ x_n \} _{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a subsequence that is convergent to some $x_0$ in $D$. Since $f$ is continuous, the sequence of values of $f$ on that subsequence converges to $x_0$ (and therefore is bounded). But, since only some *subsequence* of $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is known to converge to a point in $D$, how can we say anything about convergence (or boundedness) of $f$ on the sequence of terms in $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which are not in the convergent subsequence?

Comment: "...the sequence of values of $\;f\;$  on that subsequence converges to $\;f(x_0)\;$ ...", and thus we get a contradiction since $$\;f(x_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\implies f(x_{n_k})\xrightarrow[n_k\to\infty]{}\infty$$